# Pandas DataFrame - create new rows of data with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following data and columns. I am trying to create new observations and rows of data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'MSA': ['SF','SF','SF','SD','SD','SD','PHX','PHX','PHX'],
                   'STATE': ['CA','CA','CA','CA','CA','CA','AZ','AZ','AZ'],
                   'YR': [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21],
                   'MO': [9, 10, 11, 9, 10, 11, 9, 10, 11],
                   'VR': [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
                   'EMP': [10, 11, 12, 9, 10, 11, 7, 8, 9],
                   'GEO': ['P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P3','P3','P3']
                 })
```

I'd like to create new rows of data with a conditions for each column. Basically, for each MSA in a State, create new rows of data until the last completed month in current calendar year. So, this means create labels for `YR`, `MO` until `04` `2022`. For numeric columns `VR` and `EMP`, fill the rows with rolling average of last 3 observations. For `GEO` or any other `cat` variable simply repeat the labels for each new observations for the `MSA-STATE` group.

Note, that the obs. for `12-2021` are missing, so need to create them with `2022` values.

Comment: have you thought of using a column with datetime objects? You could create a [`pandas.TimeDelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) range of a frequency of one month

Comment: @max yes, that would help with creating new cols for `YR` and `MO` columns.

Comment: fyi - need a colon after 'GEO'

Answer (score 2):

I am just learning *to panda*, so it is not an answer, but I was curious to solve the task...
Sadly,  - I have failed... but maybe my draft will lead to any ideas...
this is my most recent test, - I will update it if I will manage to solve the "rolling mean" problem.

```
df2 = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(
        {'STATE': row.STATE,
         'MSA': row.MSA,
         'YR': 22, # original DF is integer anyway
         'MO': range(1,4), # original DF is integer anyway
         'VR': row.VR,  # cannot find the solution to get .rolling_mean() into this line
         'EMP': row.EMP, # cannot find the solution to get .rolling_mean() into this line
         'GEO': row.GEO
        }
    ) for i, row in df.iterrows()
], ignore_index=True).loc[:, ['MSA', 'STATE', 'YR', 'MO', 'VR', 'EMP', 'GEO']]
df = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=0)
df
```

if OP will solve the task, please share the result, very curious....

Out:

```
   MSA STATE  YR  MO   VR  EMP GEO
0    SF    CA  21  10  7.0   10  P1
1    SF    CA  21  11  8.0   11  P1
2    SF    CA  21  12  9.0   12  P1
3    SD    CA  21  10  5.0    9  P2
4    SD    CA  21  11  6.0   10  P2
5    SD    CA  21  12  7.0   11  P2
6   PHX    AZ  21  10  6.0    7  P3
7   PHX    AZ  21  11  7.0    8  P3
8   PHX    AZ  21  12  8.0    9  P3
0    SF    CA  22   1  7.0   10  P1
1    SF    CA  22   2  7.0   10  P1
2    SF    CA  22   3  7.0   10  P1
3    SF    CA  22   1  8.0   11  P1
4    SF    CA  22   2  8.0   11  P1
5    SF    CA  22   3  8.0   11  P1
6    SF    CA  22   1  9.0   12  P1
7    SF    CA  22   2  9.0   12  P1
8    SF    CA  22   3  9.0   12  P1
9    SD    CA  22   1  5.0    9  P2
10   SD    CA  22   2  5.0    9  P2
11   SD    CA  22   3  5.0    9  P2
12   SD    CA  22   1  6.0   10  P2
13   SD    CA  22   2  6.0   10  P2
14   SD    CA  22   3  6.0   10  P2
15   SD    CA  22   1  7.0   11  P2
16   SD    CA  22   2  7.0   11  P2
17   SD    CA  22   3  7.0   11  P2
18  PHX    AZ  22   1  6.0    7  P3
19  PHX    AZ  22   2  6.0    7  P3
20  PHX    AZ  22   3  6.0    7  P3
21  PHX    AZ  22   1  7.0    8  P3
22  PHX    AZ  22   2  7.0    8  P3
23  PHX    AZ  22   3  7.0    8  P3
24  PHX    AZ  22   1  8.0    9  P3
25  PHX    AZ  22   2  8.0    9  P3
26  PHX    AZ  22   3  8.0    9  P3
```